# How to convert ISOstring to datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am have receiving date from nodejs db controller function in  ISOString : 
2015-08-10T09:49:48.000Z

This is an ISOString not a DateString,

I want to convert it into this format "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss"

how can i do it in javascript? all the results are showing for DateString..

Comment: tryout a library like http://momentjs.com/

Comment: i wanted to do in javascript, why to use additional library ?

Comment: Because native JS has notoriously poor date handling.

Comment: can somebody pass me that link or suggest something in javascript to solve this issue ?